SharePoint List: Content of Lookup Column disappears when using conditional formatting
SharePoint and it pointless limitations (or bugs) drive me crazy again...
I have a list, that is used by different people. As it´s still not possible to color headers or similar, I got used to insert lines left or right of a column via conditional formatting. With such, I create "blocks" of columns for each user. Better than nothing... But now comes the kicker.
It worked fine so far, but now with a lookup column, the content just disappears.
This is my list without the border, numbers visible to the left.

Now with formatting applied to the left lookup column, the content is just gone.

I start with "no style" at formatting, as I only want to have the border. The teaser clearly shows, that text should be visible:

The json code has some "hidden" attributes in there, but no matter what I change, the content does not reappear.

"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",

"elmType": "div",

"style": {

"box-sizing": "border-box",

"padding": "0 2px",

"overflow": "hidden",

"text-overflow": "ellipsis"

},

"attributes": {

"class": "sp-field-borderRightBold sp-field-borderRightSolid sp-field-fontSizeMedium"

},

"children": [

{

"elmType": "span",

"style": {

"overflow": "hidden",

"text-overflow": "ellipsis",

"padding": "0 3px"

},

"txtContent": "[$PA_x0020_Nr_x002e__x003a__x0020_.lookupValue]",

"attributes": {

"class": "sp-field-fontSizeMedium"

}

}

]

}

Please help... How do I get the border AND my content?
Thanks!

Should have asked AI directly... Solution is in the code. The reference in the lookup value is not woking. By replacing it with "@currentField", the formatting works fine.

Glad that you get the solution quickly. I would request you to add your correct JSON as an answer and accept it so it will be helpful to other members in future.

Good idea, Code posted below as answer

{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "border-right": "3px solid black",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "padding": "0 3px",
        "margin-top": "-4px"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Thank you for providing a solution to the problem and showing other community members useful information!
